# how to use other function in the same controller in magento?

Tags: php, magento, controller

im trying to create new module on local. now the module is detect which is name as `IndexController.php`. this controller consist of two function which is indexAction and testAction .
now the testAction is not detect but the indexAction is detect.
im using this link to run the controller `localhost/magentoproject/index.php/test/index` which is run as expected
but when i try to run `localhost/magentoproject/index.php/test/test` is shows that 404 not found.

this is the structure
**indexController.php**

```
class Pfay_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

public function IndexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
    //echo 'test index';
}
public function testAction() {
    echo 'test mymethod';
}
}
```

[this is when im run localhost/magentoproject/index.php/test/index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUVxA.png)

[this is when im run localhost/magentoproject/index.php/test/test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEGHv.png)

Comment: try with place `die()` after `echo 'test mymethod';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path will `moduelname/controllername/actionmethod` in your case the module name will be `test` controller name will be `index` and action method will be `test`

so url will be `localhost/magentoproject/index.php/test/index/test`